# How to do a "git fast-backward"?

Tags: git

When I do a "fast-forward" merge, my current branch is updated to a new commit, and the corresponding changes are applied to my current worktree (and merged with the current uncommitted changes).

I'd like to do the same, but moving to a commit that is backward in time instead of forward.

I know how to navigate backward in time with `git checkout`, but that disconnects my worktree with its branch, which is not what I want to do.  The closest I found is `git reset` which does change my branch like I want it, but I can't figure out how to make it merge the currently uncommitted changes: with `--merge`, currently staged changes seem to be lost (!) rather than merged.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you'll do is to stash your changes, reset, and then apply the stash.